2D page walk using EPT
EPT extension defines a base register that points to level 4 page table of the hypervisor (host physical address).
When a TLB miss occurs, the page table walker takes 20 memory accesses to translate a guest virtual address into host physical address and update the TLB, plus 4 more memory accesses to store/load data/instruction. Therefore, the CR3 register, which normally contains the guest physical address of level 4 page table of the guest process, is interpreted as a virtual address by EPT and is used as per 9 bits index into the four levels of the hypervisor page tables to get the host physical address of level 4 page table of the guest process. Indexed by the leftmost 9 bits of the guest virtual address, EPT retrieves the guest physical address of level 3 page table of the guest process, and so fourth.
My question: is the above explanation exact/correct? Especially the part that considers the content of CR3 register as a virtual address?

EPT is used to translate guest physical addresses into host physical addresses when code running in VMX non-root mode loads or stores to memory. It's a mechanism that spares the VMM from having to track the guest pages.

@MargaretBloom: So EPT is separate from the hosts virtual addresses, i.e. the EPT top-level can be different from the host's current CR3?  That seems to be what the question is asking, whether EPT just means using the guest-physical address as a host-virtual address with the usual TLB entries and the same page table as other host-virtual addresses would be used after a vmexit.

@PeterCordes: yes, that's partially what I mean by my question. If the count of 24 memory accesses is exact, then my understanding would be correct, i.e., the EPT top level table should be different from CR3 host top table, and guest physical addresses are treated as virtual addresses by EPT.
